# What could be the shortest way of checking function parameter , which might have values 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 in C#

Tags: c#

I have a function in C# which looks like :

```
public static void OnlyValidInput ( int parameterName ) 
{
    if ( parameterName == 0 || parameterName ==1 ||
         parameterName == 2 ...)
{
     ... do Ok stuff
}
else 
{ throw new CustomException ( "invalid param should be 0 , 1 , 2" );
}
}
```

How to make it shorter ...

Thanks all , the answer showed what I was thinking about, but was not able to describe it ...

Answer (score 13):

```
if (parameterName >= 0 && parameterName <= 3)
```

If you expect it to be continous.

Comment: Title says "0, 1, 2, 3".  Code has a .. have 2 so I presumed that he just dropped off the 3.

Comment: `if (0 <= parameterName && parameterName <= 3)` is more obvious and easier check to my eyes.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps OT, but in your code example I would rather throw an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I would separate out your concerns into 2 methods.  One to validate input and the other to actually do stuff.  It looks like you have a high and low value for the parameterName value.  If so change this to be a less than, greater than check vs. explicitly checking every single value

```
public static bool IsValid(int parameterName) {
  return (parameterName >= 0) && (parameterName <= 2);
}

public static void OnlyValidInput(int parameterName) {
  if ( !IsValid(parameterName) ) {
    throw new CustomExceptoin("...");
  }
  .. Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to be silly ...

```
if((parameterName & 0xFFFFFFFC) == 0) // Check if value is 0, 1, 2, 3
```

Basically it's just checking to see if there are only ones in the low two bits (which is only true for 0, 1, 2, 3)

I wouldn't ever actually do that; the `&&` method is much clearer ...

Answer (score 1):

To get compile-time checking create an enum with values for each your valid arguments and pass that as a parameter instead of an int.

Of course, if you have a very large range this won't work so well, but if it's really just 0 through 2 that sounds more like those number mean something that should be .. enumerated .. anyway.

Comment: Would that disallow using (MyEnum)0x123?

Comment: Tnx, could you post a small example

Comment: @Dainel L: Interesting! Thanks for that one... :)

Comment: Good point- you'd still need to check the argument.  I'm not a fan of casting to enum in most cases, though, and I still think if it really is just 0-2 there's probably something there that should be named anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void OnlyValidInput ( int parameterName ) 
{
     if( new int[]{0,1,2}.Contains(parameterName))
     {
        //... do Ok stuff
     }
     else throw new CustomException ( "invalid param should be 0 , 1 , 2" );
}
```

Answer (score -7):

```
public enum Parameter
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
}

public void SomeMethod(Parameter p)
{
    Int32 pAsInteger = (Int32)p; // Here I am casting the parameter to an Integer
}

SomeMethod((Parameter)2); // Here I am casting an integer to enum of type Parameter
```

The method accepts only the enumerator of type Parameter.

You should of course not rename your enumerator and it's values to something descriptive and easy to comprehend.

Comment: See the comments to my answer: you could still cast an invalid value as a Parameter enum.

Comment: That doesnt't validate input.  The following compiles just fine.  SomeMethod((Parameter)42);

Comment: That's true.. If the parameters original type is an Integer. If not; then this is the way to go in my opinion. You might want to chime in on this, Don Ronny